# xamarin.iOS call API after every x seconds when app is backgrounded

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to call an API to save my local data(if not saved to the server) to the server even when app is in the background. I have tried calling API in Device.StartTimer with 10 sec timespan, but in iOS it doesn't call if app is in the background.
Is there any way to call API after every x seconds ?
Can shiny library (https://allanritchie.com/posts/shinyjobs) help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with your call in ios backgrounding task, you can check this doucument to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks

Comment: According to the docs, when app enters into the background then background task can only have 600 seconds. But I want to check every x minutes that data has been pushed to the server or not until the app is in the background.

Comment: You can perform tasks for a limited time after your application is directed to go to the background, but only for the duration provided. Running for longer than this will cause your application to be terminated.